# Weird performance behavior when traversing a list

Tags: scala

The following code produces some weird results:

```
object Solution {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val nums = io.Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\Sagi\\Desktop\\input.txt") /*stdin*/ .getLines().toList drop 1 map (_ toInt)
    val k = (nums take 1)(0)
    val sorted = (nums drop 1).sorted
    println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)
    start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var unifairness = Int.MaxValue
    for(i <- 0 until (sorted.length - k);
      diff = sorted(i + k - 1) - sorted(i)
      if diff < unifairness
    ) unifairness = diff
    println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start)
    println(unifairness)
  }
}
```

What's weird is that the first print of time is less then a second on my machine and runs sorted which takes O(NlogN) the second print takes 20-30 seconds and supposedly runs in O(N)

BTW I tried using `.view.force` on the sorted list, tried a while loop, also I tried a recursive traversal with `@tailrec` for stack space optimization

The input file is just a text file of 100,000 lines with an integer in each line

Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: Have you tried profiling it, visualvm comes with the JDK and allows you to perform both sampled and traced cpu profiling. Maybe that will give you some insight into what is happening?

Comment: Unrelated, but are you also searching for the `head` and `tail` methods? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`List`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.List)s are O(n) for random access by index, not O(1). You want something that extends [`IndexedSeq`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.IndexedSeq), such as a [`Vector`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector), or an [`Array`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.Array)<sup>1</sup>. The methods `toVector` and `toArray` are available on all instances of `TraversableOnce` (thus all instances of `Seq` or `Iterator`) and work just like `toList`.

(<sup>1</sup> An `Array` is not really an `IndexedSeq`, but it will be converted into one via `WrappedArray` when necessary.)

Comment: thank you, adding .toVector on the end of the val sorted initialization solves it